# "One should respect the {religion / religions} of others."

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-number

> **One** should respect the **religion** of others as much as one's.
>  
>   **One** should respect the **religions** of others as much as one's.

One behaves as **singular** and takes singular noun/pronoun and helping verb. 
So, we should be using **religion** in the sentence. But the answer to the question is **religions**. Is there any rule I am missing?

Comment: If someone's religious law demands that they punch me in the ear once a year, I will respect their religion -- by refusing to allow them to be in a position to enforce their religious law.

Answer (score 3):

A single person can follow multiple religions. So, if you are suggesting someone to respect others' religions, it's quite valid. The latter part of the sentence, though, needs some correction. I have made the correction in bold.

> One should respect the **religions** of others as much as **one's own**.